# Issue with UILabel not loading in a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ok, so I have a `UIView` in my view controller, when I run my program the `UIView` is displayed fine, when I put either a `UILabel`, `Button` or anything else in the `UIView` it wont display when run, it only displays when the UIView is on its own, it also works when there is a `UIImageView` or `UITextField` in it. Any suggestions why this may happen and how to fix it?

Edit: The console is showing that the label and `UIView` does exist and it 'on the screen' but I cant seem to see it.

Comment: can you please post some sample code? Code where you initialized and added the UIView, and code where you aded the buttons/labels

Comment: @Soule all was done is storyBoard as it is easier for me to achieve this certain look.

Comment: can you take a screenshot like this http://grab.by/vNvE .. the sidebar part is the most important

Comment: @Soule https://www.dropbox.com/s/2q49b8lvignyol8/Screen%20Shot%202014-04-06%20at%2010.00.37%20pm.png

Comment: Which simulator/device are you using to run this app?

Comment: @Damir179 iPhone Retnia, simulator

Comment: what is uiview name and your uilabel name

Comment: I seen your dropbox screen shot, u were not declare the subview of UIview of your UIlabel

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a position problem. Can you NSLog the position?